# Angular javascript page compiles but shows blank

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I compile my Angular app it works, but the HTML page is blank and it my application will not display. I've had issues like this before and usually it has been one of the Imports, but I'm not sure now. When I use Google Chrome to inspect, the error that I see is **record.factory is not a function**. Is anyone familiar with this?

Here is my module.ts code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { ItemService } from './items.service';
import { NewItemFormComponent } from './new-item-form/new-item-form.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'; 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewItemFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ItemService, BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed in wrong place couple of your modules. You should put them into `imports` section, not `providers`. I am talking

```
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FormsModule
```

Also there might be problem if you have `@Injectable` and `@NgModule` decorators added to same class.